# How to remove the index.php from url in codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a website in Codeigniter. This is very common issue I know and there are lots of solutions on Stack Overflow. I try almost all but nothing is helpful for me.

I just want to remove index.php from my url. Anybody please tell me how can I do it?

I have removed index.php from the config file's `$config['index_page']` section

I also checked  `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';` mode try both mode auto and `REQUEST_URI`.

My .httaccess file structure right now is this:

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
```

Can anybody please tell me how to do it?

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you update your links http://www.codeigniter.com/docs you will find now old and new user guide ellislab does not deal with CI Any more

Comment: @wolfgang1983 ok thanks for the info. Pity the search engines dont seem to have caught up with this change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=> Change in config file :-

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://123456/proj/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

=> change in .htaccess file :-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|
(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: works now.. there was little issue the .httacess file was in application folder I place that in root folder of project now its work for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$config['uri_protocol']` should be `REQUEST_URI` and then `.htaccess` as follows

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: not working see here 
http://chandigarhpropertyonline.com/music/Home this is not opening

http://chandigarhpropertyonline.com/music/index.php/Home

this is opening

Answer (score 0):

I have the following and works fine for me:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the config file like this:

`$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';`

2. Use the following .htaccess:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

Note: `.htaccess` vary depending on server. In some server (e.g.: Godaddy) need to use the following `.htaccess`:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /music
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Rewrite Base **/music** is your folder name

Comment: not working see here 
http://chandigarhpropertyonline.com/music/Home this is not opening

http://chandigarhpropertyonline.com/music/index.php/Home

this is opening

Comment: added but not working I badly want its solution. I try almost everything but I am not able to remove index.php