# CodeIgniter removing index.php from URL not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Hi following are the changes I have made to remove `index.php` from URL

replaced `$config['index_page'] = "index.php"`

to `$config['index_page'] = ""`

then replace `$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"`

by `$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"`

then I added below code in `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

but this isn't working. Any Idea, what is wrong ?

Comment: check this url :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132494/how-to-remove-the-index-php-from-url-in-codeigniter-project/37133083#37133083

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to edit index.php, replace the content .htaccess file to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: and also if it does not work, try to put it in all htaccess file on your project :)

Comment: thanks,i have tried this but not working for me. i have updated config.php not index.php.... also waht do you mean by  "try to put it in all htaccess file on your project"

Comment: on my project, i have ht access on outside the application folder, and inside application folder.
how come it is not working? what's the error?

Comment: rules works but i made silly mistake. i just missed .(dot) in .htaccess file name:(

Comment: not working for me too... only logout got this problem

Answer (score 0):

Please try using following code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know but i think the last thing you need to do is on your Apache. httpd.conf

Change

```
AllowOverride None
```

To

```
AllowOverride All
```

Also may i know where your .htaccess is located?

Answer (score 0):

Place the .htaccess file in the project folder like this:

htdocs/your_project/.htaccess

Try this new code for .htaccess:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
  </IfModule>
```

Don't try to delete the other .htaccess file that is already in your application folder.

Changes in config.php are as follows:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_project_name/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Don't use:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

Hope it will perfectly work fine for you.